# TypeScript error in findOneBy in TypeOrm with NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Trying to build something with NestJS. Setup TypeORM, entities, controllers etc. But getting TS error when trying to update. (I think) All okay, but what id the problem? Context below.

User Entity

```js
@Entity('users')
export class User {
  // ...

  @OneToMany(() => Report, (report) => report.user)
  reports: Report[];

  @OneToMany(() => Feed, (feed) => feed.user)
  feeds: Feed[];
}
```

Feed Entity

```js
@Entity('feeds')
export class Feed {
  // ...

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.feeds)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'user_id',
  })
  user: User;
}
```

Later in `feeds.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class FeedsService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Feed) private repo: Repository<Feed>) {}

async update(
    id: number,
    updateFeedDto: UpdateFeedDto,
    user: User,
    attachment?: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    // find the feed when owned by this user
    const feed = await this.repo.findOneBy({
      //                               ^^^^ this is feedsRepo
      id,
      user: user,
      //^^ TS2322: Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOperator<any> |
      // FindOptionsWhere<User> | FindOptionsWhere<User>[] | EqualOperator<User> | undefined'.
      // Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<User>'.
      // Types of property 'reports' are incompatible.
      // Type 'Report[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOperator<any> |
      // FindOptionsWhere<Report> | FindOptionsWhere<Report>[] | EqualOperator<Report> | undefined'
    });

    // then do the updating
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly, are you asking why you cannot find by user object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following syntax to fix this.
`feeds.service.ts`

```js
  async update(
    id: number,
    updateFeedDto: UpdateFeedDto,
    user: User,
    attachment?: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    const feed = await this.repo.findOneBy({
      id,
      user: {
        id: user.id,
      },
    });

    console.log({
      feed,
    });

    // then do the updating
  }
```